# prove this poisson inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading the section on Poisson's equation on the book Partial Differential Equations by Evans, on page 24 he writes the following inequality for $|I_{\epsilon}|$, which I'm having a hard time trying to see why it holds.

**definition of** $I_{\epsilon}$:

$\Delta u(x) = \int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy+\int_{\mathbb{R}^n-B(0,\epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy = : I_{\epsilon} + J_{\epsilon}$

**inequality:**

$|I_{\epsilon}| \leq C||D^2f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \int_{B(0,\epsilon)}|\Phi(y)|dy$

On this page there is another inequality for the quantity $|L_{\epsilon}|$ that he defines later on and which don't understand too, but maybe if I see why the above inequality holds I can figure the other one.

I understand this question is vague but this is the best I could do.

I've looked on other sources but all of them use this inequality with no explanation. For example here http://web.iitd.ac.in/~vvksrini/Fund-laplace.pdf on page 4.

You may be asking yourself why someone that doesn't understand this is reading such an advanced book, this is a "honors" project in a real analysis course I'm taking.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it not just

\begin{align}
I_{\epsilon} &= \int_{B(0, \epsilon)} \Phi(y) \Delta_{x} f(x - y) dy \\ 
\implies \lvert{I_{\epsilon}}\rvert &= \bigg \lvert \int_{B(0, \epsilon)} \Phi(y) \Delta_{x} f(x - y) dy \bigg \rvert \\
&\le \int_{B(0, \epsilon)} \lvert \Phi(y) \Delta_{x} f(x - y) \rvert dy \\
&\le \max \lvert \Delta_{x} f \rvert \int_{B(0, \epsilon)} \lvert \Phi(y) \rvert dy \\
\end{align}

Comment: @Mattos I don't understand the step from line 3 to line 4. Explain it to me please.

Comment: All I've said is that the integral of the convolution of $f$ and $\Phi$ is less than or equal to the _maximum value_ of $f$ multiplied by the integral of $\Phi$.